# Angular 4 dynamic reactive form on Drop down form API [add and remove]

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I'm facing the issue in angular 4 projects I would be grateful If you find time to resolve the issue.

### Objective

On the change of dropdown value we need to call API on the basis of returned value we need to populate form data. [API will follow same object structure]

1. The for loop I have mentioned in the block is not running completely to empty the form controls array.
2. I have gone through FormGroup and FormArray classes there is no method to remove All controls.
3. May be approach is not correct, due to incomplete knowledge of angular4.
4. Fragments of source code :

```js
    availableToolsForNewEvnList: Array<ToolsForNewEvn>;
    selectedToolsForNewEvnList: Array<ToolsForNewEvn>;

    getProjects() { //Working Fine
        this.devopsToolService.getProjects()
            .subscribe(
            projectList => {
                this.projectList = projectList as Project[];
                this.projectList.slice(0, 1).map(p => {
                    this.selectedProject = p;
                    this.onChange(p);
                });
            },
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }


    getDevopAllToolsPojo(projectId: number) { //Error Block
        this.devopsToolService.getDevopAllToolsPojo(projectId)
            .subscribe(
            projectAllToolList => {
                this.projectAllToolList = projectAllToolList as DevopToolsPojo[];
                let control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['devopToolsPojo'];//ERROR in this block:Start
                console.log("BEFORE" + control.length);
                console.log(control);
                for (let i = 0; i < control.length; i++) {
                    console.log("Loop [ " + control.length + " ]");
                    console.log(control);
                    control.removeAt(i)
                }
                console.log("AFTER" + control.length);
                console.log(control);//ERROR in this block:END
                projectAllToolList.forEach(p => {
                    const addrCtrl = this.initDevopToolsPojo(p);
                    control.push(addrCtrl);
                });
                this.myForm.patchValue(projectAllToolList); //Working Fine
            },
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
        this.myForm.controls['projectId'].setValue(projectId);//Working Fine
    }

    getDevopToolsPojo(projectId: number) { //Working Fine
        this.devopsToolService.getDevopToolsPojo(projectId)
            .subscribe(
            projectToolList => {
                this.projectToolList = projectToolList as DevopToolsPojo[];
            },
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }

    getNewDevopToolsPojo(projectId: number) { //Working Fine
        this.devopsToolService.getNewDevopToolsPojo(projectId)
            .subscribe(
            tl => {
                this.availableToolsForNewEvnList = tl as ToolsForNewEvn[];
            },
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }

    onChange(selectedProject) { //Working Fine
        this.selectedProject = selectedProject;
        this.getDevopToolsPojo(selectedProject.projectId);
        this.getDevopAllToolsPojo(selectedProject.projectId);
        this.getNewDevopToolsPojo(selectedProject.projectId);
    }

    initDevopToolsPojo(p) { //Working Fine
        return this._fb.group({
            'devopToolId': [p.devopToolId],
            'url': [p.url],
            'userName': [p.userName],
            'password': [p.password],
            'accessKey': [p.accessKey],
            'secureKey': [p.secureKey],
            'toolName': [p.toolName],
            'toolId': [p.toolId],
            'toolDesc': [p.toolDesc],
            'configured': [p.configured],
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm = this._fb.group({
            'projectId': [''],
            'devopToolsPojo': this._fb.array([])
        });
        this.initDevopToolsPojo(new DevopToolsPojo());
        this.selectedProject = new Project();
        this.getProjects();
    }

    constructor(
        private devopsToolService: DevopsToolService,
        private _fb: FormBuilder
    ) {
        this.availableToolsForNewEvnList = new Array<ToolsForNewEvn>();
        this.selectedToolsForNewEvnList = new Array<ToolsForNewEvn>();
    }
```

### Console logs:

> ```
> **12:42:03.564 devops-tool.component.ts:70 ##BEFORE7
>
> 12:42:03.565 devops-tool.component.ts:71 FormArray {validator: null, asyncValidator: null, _pristine: true, _touched: false, _onCollectionChange: function…}
>
> 12:42:03.569 devops-tool.component.ts:73 ##Loop [ 7 ]
>
> 12:42:03.571 devops-tool.component.ts:74 FormArray {validator: null, asyncValidator: null, _pristine: true, _touched: false, _onCollectionChange: function…}
>
> 12:42:03.572 devops-tool.component.ts:73 ##Loop [ 6 ]
>
> 12:42:03.573 devops-tool.component.ts:74 FormArray {validator: null, asyncValidator: null, _pristine: true, _touched: false, _onCollectionChange: function…}
>
> 12:42:03.574 devops-tool.component.ts:73 ##Loop [ 5 ]
>
> 12:42:03.575 devops-tool.component.ts:74 FormArray {validator: null, asyncValidator: null, _pristine: true, _touched: false, _onCollectionChange: function…}
>
> 12:42:03.576 devops-tool.component.ts:73 ##Loop [ 4 ]
>
> 12:42:03.577 devops-tool.component.ts:74 FormArray {validator: null, asyncValidator: null, _pristine: true, _touched: false, _onCollectionChange: function…}
>
> 12:42:03.578 devops-tool.component.ts:77 ##AFTER3** 
>
> ***//There are 3 more records to be remove form list.*
>
> 12:42:03.580 devops-tool.component.ts:78 FormArray {validator: null, asyncValidator: null, _pristine: true, _touched: false, _onCollectionChange: function…}
>
> 12:42:03.583 devops-tool.component.ts:80 (7) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]**
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a [Form array](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) you can set the controls to an empty array:

```js
removeAllQuestions() {
  console.log(this.myForm.get('devopToolsPojo'));
  this.questionForm.get('devopToolsPojo').controls = [];
  console.log(this.myForm.get('devopToolsPojo'));
}
```

[Live plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/BRojKYjXV3mr01vxw3Ug?p=preview)

Comment: Hi There, Thanks for the valuable suggestion. It resolved my problem in a different way.

 (<FormArray>this.myForm.controls['devopToolsPojo']).controls = [];

this.questionForm.get('devopToolsPojo').controls = [];

//This statement will not work(with Angular CLI 1.2.4) because of following

get method is called from AbstractControl which has no variable named controls as per my Understanding. So I have typecast it and It worked for me.

Comment: If you change the type from `AbstractControl` to `FormArray` or `FormGroup` it should work - glad you got it sorted anyway

Answer (score 0):

You are removing items from an array you are iterating over which not a good idea no mater what technology you use.

You can create a duplicate of the array you are iterating through and remove items from the duplicate array while iterating over original array

or

Iterate through an array but build a new array if an item from the original array fulfills some criteria.

In any case by avoiding addition and removal of items (*from an array you are iterating over*) will save you a lot of headache.

Comment: This is a good approach - `filter` would work well with for this